# replacing strings within a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, function, replace

I have a pandas data frame with a column named "content" that contains text. I want to remove some words from each text within this column. I thought of replacing each string by empty string, but when I print the result of my function I see that the words have not been removed. My code is below:

```
def replace_words(t):
  words = ['Livre', 'Chapitre', 'Titre', 'Chapter', 'Article' ]
  for i in t:
    if i in words:
      t.replace (i, '')
    else:
      continue
  print(t)


st = 'this is Livre and Chapitre and Titre and Chapter and Article'

replace_words(st)
```

An example of desired result is: 'this is and and and and '

With the code below I want to apply the function above to each text in the column "content":

```
df['content'].apply(lambda x: replace_words(x))
```

Can someone help me to create a function that removes all the words I need and then apply this function to all the texts within my df column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).
Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID' : np.arange(4),
    'words' : ['this is Livre and Chapitre and Titre and Chapter and Article', 
               'this is car and Chapitre and bus and Chapter and Article',
              'this is Livre and Chapitre',
              'nothing to replace']
})
```

```
words = ['Livre', 'Chapitre', 'Titre', 'Chapter', 'Article']
pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, words))
print(pat)
'Livre|Chapitre|Titre|Chapter|Article'
```

```
df['words'] = df['words'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

```
   ID                               words
0   0        this is  and  and  and  and 
1   1  this is car and  and bus and  and 
2   2                       this is  and 
3   3                  nothing to replace
```

Comment: much better: `df['words'] = df['words'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True)`

Comment: If you are using stopwords including a, e, i, o, u or syllables, str.replace removes those letters or syllables inside words. I had that problem and solved it using: `df['words'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (words)]))`

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. If you split using `for i in t:` each `i` is a letter, not a word.
2. t.replace does not work inplace

Use this:

```
def replace_words(t):
    words = ['Livre', 'Chapitre', 'Titre', 'Chapter', 'Article' ]
    for i in t.split(' '):
        # print(i) # remove to see problem 1
        if i in words:
            t= t.replace (i, '')
        else:
            continue
    # print(t)
    return t
```

Edit: You can directly call `df['col'].apply(replace_words)`.

Comment: ok, the function works perfectly but after applying the function to the column using df['col'].apply(replace_words) I don't see the words replaced in texts of the columns

Comment: did you test returning the `t` variable in the final of the function?

Comment: Exactly, you have to return `t` and not just print it